# How to populate a column of type "timestamp with time zone" at pgAdmin as a unix time?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin to browse a database hosted at Heroku. I am trying to create new records but I am getting an error because there is a column of type `timestamp with time zone`. I want the time zone to be `UTC+3`. Here is what I have tried, but I am getting an error:

[image: pgAdmin problematic format]

Here is the value if you need to copy/paste it:

```
1477357140.0+03
```

Is there any method to create the records without converting the timestamp value from the unix-time format?

Comment: `timestamp with time zone` column most certainly does not contain such a value. What is the error you get? If you want to display the value in a different time zone use `at time zone 'UTC+3'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's a value that I am writing by myself. I know that it is wrong but I don't know how to write it in a proper way. Here is the error: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "1477357140.0+03"`

Comment: That's not a valid constant for a timestamp https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#id-1.5.7.13.18.7

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I saw this link before asking but I thought that maybe there is a way to enter the timestamp as unix-time format. Thank you. I will convert all of timestamps to an acceptable format by postgres.

Comment: In plain SQL you can do `to_timestamp(1477357140.0) at time zone 'UTC+3';` - but I don't think that's more readable or easier to type then `timestamptz '2016-10-25T02:59+03:00'`